# Debugging xor-swap for Insertion Sort using java

Tags: java, sorting

My insertion sort using xor- swap is not working ,  but without xor-swap its working fine.
How can i fix my xor-swap insertion sort algorithm ?

Insertion sort without xor-swap -

```
//sorts the given array in " increasing order "
   private static void insertionSort(char[] array) {
     // save the length of array 
      final  int  LENGTH = array.length ;

    //loop through selecting second character as  first element is already sorted
        for(int i = 1 ; i < LENGTH ; ++i )
             {
            char current  =  array[i];
            //place the array[i] in "order" with elements placed towards left of itself
                  for( int j = i - 1 ; (j >=0 && array[j+1] < array[j]) ; --j )
                  {


                      array[j+1] = array[j] ;
                      array[j] = current ;
                  }
              }



    }
```

With xor- swap --

```
//sorts the given array in " increasing order "
    private static void insertionSort(char[] array) {
         // save the length of array 
          final  int  LENGTH = array.length ;

          //loop through selecting second character as  first element is already sorted
          for(int i = 1 ; i < LENGTH ; ++i )
    {
              //char current  =  array[i];
     //place the array[i] in "order" with elements placed towards left of itself
              for( int j = i - 1 ; (j >=0 && array[j+1] < array[j]) ; --j )
              {

                  array[j+1] ^= array[j] ^=  array[j+1] ^= array[j] ;
                  //array[j] = current ;
              }
          }




    }
```

Thank you

Comment: I have no idea how that single line is parsed; are you really sure you do? Why not write it out as a sequence of assignments; not only will it be more readable, you may well find it starts working.

Comment: I bet it's slower than the original, once you get it working. (Micro-optimising an O(N^2) sort implementation is a bit of a waste anyway, surely?)

Comment: just experimenting  , and yeah xor-swap do works [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm)

Comment: I know xor swap works; I'm just not convinced you've implemented it properly. (And you seem to have proved that you haven't.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The order of execution is right-associative with the `^=` operator, so the code you have written is equivalent to:

```
a ^= (b ^= (a ^= b));
```

The ^= operator is just shorthand for a = a ^ b, so if you fully expand this you get:

```
a = a ^ (b = b ^ (a = a ^ b));
```

Now remember that the value of `a` will be taken at the start of evaluation of the expression, not at the moment of execution. Imagine `a` and `b` take the values `5` and `10`. You're effectively computing:

```
a = 5 ^ (b = 10 ^ (a = 5 ^ 10));
```

You actually need that first `5` to be `15` for the swap to work.

So, as Alan Stokes has indicated, you need to separate out the expression into three (or just maybe two) statements in order to tell the compiler that the result of each one should be used in the next stage of calculation.

```
a ^= b;
b ^= a;
a ^= b;
```

Comment: I know many C based languages. The way Java treats op-assignments is rather special.